# warning #411: class foo defines no constructor to initialize the following:

Tags: c++, c

I have some legacy code built with c++ compiler giving the error in the subject line

```
typedef struct foo {
    char const * const str;
 } Foo;
```

and a lot of places in the code (meaning I cannot change all of them) use it in a C style initialization:

```
 Foo arr[] ={
     {"death"},
     {"turture"},
     {"kill"}
  }
```

What is the good workaround to remove the stupid warning?

Comment: You might want to point out the compiler which emits this.

Comment: Are you using a C compiler or a C++ compiler? What's the result of `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof 'a');` on your compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works anyway, you might as well disable the warning in the command line for those files.

With gcc I think it's something like `-wd411`.

Not so elegant, but if it works and if the code appears to be compliant to the standard (in this order) there's no point sweating over it!

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the const pointer after construction.  You need a constructor initializer to initialize 'str'.

```
struct Foo
{
  const char* const str;
  explicit Foo(const char* str_) : str(str_) {}
};
```

Note that 'typedef' is not required in C++ for a case like this.

EDIT:

If you can't use a constructor, then you must make your pointer non-const:

```
struct Foo
{
  const char* str;
};
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

After litb's comment, I tried the original code and it does indeed compile (g++ 4.1.2 and XL C/C++ 8.0) with no warnings.  Perhaps the compiler in question is doing a construction followed by assignment in this case?  I used less violent strings, but I doubt that would make a difference.  ;v)

Comment: it doesnt address the problem, cuz I cannot define a constructor as it will break the rest of the code.

Comment: 'explicit' prevents implicit conversion.  For example, if you had a function that accepted a const reference to Foo, you couldn't just pass a char* to it and have a Foo implicitly created.

Comment: However, why is his original code not valid or bad (thus giving a warning?)? I don't see him changing the pointer afterwards.

Comment: @litb: Well, you're more knowledgeable about the standards than I am.  How is the initialization handled in a case like this?  Are the array member constructed using the initial values, or are they default-construct (since there's no constructor defined) and then assigned?  If it's the latter case, my answer is right.  If it's the former, maybe I'm not right.

Comment: This is aggregate initialization which, as the name implies, is initialization, not assignment. The warning does seem a lot like one that simply arises because the compiler is too old.

Comment: @coppro: I believe you're right.  However, my answer may be a usable workaround for the OP's compiler issue.  I'll leave the answer up for now.

Comment: @Andrei - how does adding an explicit constructor break the rest of the code?

Comment: @Bill, It's going to forbid initializing the class with braces like `{ "hello" }`

Answer (score 1):

Check the compiler's documentation to see if there's a workaround. Your code is perfectly compliant, so without any more information, it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0):

Intel compiler did this. Seems to be a bug. The trick is to remove the second "const" from the structure.

You can still make the array const and this will prevent modification of the pointer. IE:

```
typedef struct foo {
  char const * str;
} Foo;

const Foo arr[] ={
    {"death"},
    {"turture"},
    {"kill"}
}
```