# How do you handle "warning #370-D: class "match_str" defines no constructor"

Tags: c++03

The following structure:

```
struct match_str {
    const char*   s;    // Pointer to string
    const uint8_t l;    // Length
};
```

Is intended to be initialized only as follows:

```
const match_str s = {"200 OK", 5};
```

and used as normal struct with constant members.  During compilation time, I get the following warning:

`warning #370-D: class "match_str" defines no constructor to initialize the following: const member "match_str::l"`

What can I do with the warning?  I get the warning, it makes sense, but I am not sure how to handle it.  Basically, this is a *safer* c-string structure that I use in my code, and each instance is hand written like the `const char*`

Reference:

- [Is this warning alright - "#368-D: <entity> defines no constructor to initialize the following:"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126171/is-this-warning-alright-368-d-entity-defines-no-constructor-to-initialize)
- [warning #411: class foo defines no constructor to initialize the following:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607357/warning-411-class-foo-defines-no-constructor-to-initialize-the-following)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the `const` in the struct, and make the instances of the struct `const`, which will serve the purpose of keeping members constant.